# How can ı change nan or string values to average of the column to which it belongs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pyqt5

```
df = pd.read_csv(self.table_name)

for j in df.values:
    for k in j[0:-1]:
        try:
            k = float(k)
        except ValueError:
            df.replace(to_replace=k,value=np.nan,inplace=True)

df.replace(to_replace=np.nan, value=df.mean(), inplace=True)



# df.fillna(df.mean(), inplace=True)
df.to_csv(self.table_name, index=False)
print(df)
```

[image: This is my dataframe]

> If the data has string values ​​while entering the training, it may
> not enter the training. In order to prevent this, I created a function
> that becomes active with a button, but the string values ​​​​are
> deleted in the first run, and in the second run, I get the result I
> want. I made the button and its function over pyqt5. When the user
> clicks the button I mentioned, he connects to this function and its
> functions respectively. But where is the problem I could not solve, is
> there anyone who can help?

Comment: Providing text instead of images helps to get faster recommendations from the community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom function for all columns without first selected by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with convert values to numeric with [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) and `errors='coerce'`, so if created missing values for not parseable values. Last replace them by `mean` in [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
def f(x):
    s = pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')
    return s.fillna(s.mean())


df.iloc[:, 1:]= df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(f)
```